# What is the difference between installing QT by an .exe installer and by building from source package

Tags: qt

I know there is two ways to install QT: one is to simply use the installer, and the other is to build qt from its source package ([Building Qt Desktop for Windows with MSVC](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC)).

The second method is tedious and time-consuming. I want to know why we bother to do the building process rather than go for the simple installation. Are there any special advantages for that?

Comment: Qt you have several configurations, when you use the online method you use Qt with standard configurations, on the other hand if you compile it directly you can activate or deactivate certain features. for example some libraries are unnecessary so you can omit them at the time of compilation.

Comment: @jingweimo, simply: If you build Qt manually without change .. you end up getting same as the pre-build version!

Comment: @ if that is the difference, the online method seems more general-purpose, assuming I don't what specific features I need to deactivate.

Comment: @MohammadKanan: thanks for your answer!

Comment: @eyllanesc, is that really a good reason ? can't you omit prebuild libraries .. why not?

Comment: @jingweimo, the good thing also is .. even when you have a pre-build qt .. YOU CAN still rebuild any particular qt package IF NEEDED.

Comment: If you want to statically link the Qt libraries, building from scratch is your _only_ option.

Comment: @MohammadKanan: I am now working on a project requiring using QT. My colleague stresses that I have to build QT to use it, and do not use the exe installer. I just don't appreciate such a limitation with the online installation.

Comment: @jingweimo, cant get you .. what is _the limitation with the online installer_ ?? it does not have limitations .. for inexperienced with Qt .. better use online installer

Comment: @MohammadKanan I think you did not understand me, it's one of the things, for example I wanted to activate some sqlite functionality that deactivated Qt, so the way I solved it was to compile it directly. There are other reasons such as statically link , compilation for particular platforms such as embedded, etc.

Comment: @MohammadKanan  Not that serious 'limitation'. The building processes has some benefits, e.g. selective features, statically linking, as discussed above.